# Python 3 with SQLITE3 - "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" when selecting fields

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite

```
import sqlite3
def test(id,table):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('database/db.sqlite3')
    with conn:
        cur = conn.cursor()
        data = cur.execute(f"SELECT id FROM {table} WHERE id=?",(id,))
        return data.fetchone()

id = test(2,'example')
if id:
    print('id found')
```

I'm getting this error, I don't know what I'm writing incorrectly? :

```
tomas@tomas-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/PasivicSoftware$ python3 test.py
  File "test.py", line 6
    data = cur.execute(f"SELECT id FROM {table} WHERE id=?",(id,))
                                                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: You are using python 3.6 syntax with an older python.

Comment: Remove that "f".

Comment: ok thanks. the downvotes were unnecessary I started with 3.6 version I did not know 3.5 didn't have f strings.

Comment: I agree that the question is totally valid, and was asked in a correct way. I upvoted it to compensate for your downvotes.

Answer (score 0):

You have a stray `f` inside cur.execute before your query string.

Comment: That is not stray, it is a f-string. OP used it to replace the `{table}` inside the string with that variable's contents. You need python 3.6 to use it though.

Comment: Huh, TIL; looks like it was added pretty recently; thanks for the tip!